# Ticklabel wrong in go.Figure

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, bar-chart

I have build a go.Bar-Figure from a data frame with a time series index. I'm using the resample("Y").sum() function to show values for every of of each category. It works fine. But the tick label is wrong.
As you can see the tick label shows for example "2008". But the summarised values are in the period from "2017-01-01":"2017-12-31".
I have read a lot of tick format and tick labels in the plotly documentation but I can't find the solution for my problem.
I hope it's not very difficult to solve this problem.
Here is the `go.Bar` figure of sum of values per year:
[image: go.Bar figure of sum of values per year]

Here is the output from:

```
`df_jahresniederschlag.head().to_dict()`
```

> {'SDO_ID': {Timestamp('2004-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 85928,
> Timestamp('2005-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 340910,
> Timestamp('2006-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 340910,
> Timestamp('2007-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 340910,
> Timestamp('2008-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 341844},  'Wert':
> {Timestamp('2004-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 189.00000000000006,
> Timestamp('2005-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 768.2,
> Timestamp('2006-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 735.5000000000005,
> Timestamp('2007-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 1111.9999999999995,
> Timestamp('2008-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 626.4000000000002}}

And this is my code for building figure:

`fig_jahr=go.Figure()`

```
for name in df_alle_stationen.SDO_Name.unique():
 df_jahresniederschlag = df_alle_stationen.loc[df_alle_stationen["SDO_Name"]==name].resample("Y").sum()
   fig_jahr.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df_jahresniederschlag.index,y=df_jahresniederschlag["Wert"], name=name)
```

Here is an another example. In this first picture you can see a plotly go.Bar() figure based on a data frame with resampled datas (resample("m").sum()).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sahTd.png)

The second picture shows the output of "df.head().to_dict()".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VymjZ.png)

the third a graphic with plot method. In the last picture the tick labels are correct.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hwh9h.png)

Comment: Is it possible to provide the code and sample data that you are currently working on? It would help us to get an answer more quickly. It is recommended that you provide the data as a text file.

Comment: can you include the text from `df.head().to_dict()` in your question? that would help us see what kind of date format you have and help us reproduce the issue you're having as @r-beginners said

Comment: OK. Here are the code for my figure and the output form df.head:

Comment: Some new pictures are added. They shows the same issues as in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for a correct label using tick mode, tick0 dtick:

```
fig_jahr.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df_jahresniederschlag.index,y=df_jahresniederschlag["Wert"], name=name)
    fig_jahr.update_xaxes(
            tickangle = 45,
            title_text = "Jahr",
            title_font = {"size": 14,"color":"black"},
            tickmode="linear",
            tick0=df_jahresniederschlag.index.strftime("%Y-%m")[0],
            dtick="M12",
            tickformat="%Y"
    )
```